# Blocking packets on a local network

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to develop a code where I can test error conditions of a client connected to a web server by filtering and blocking some type of packets.

For starters, I want to analyse the behavior of the client when it cannot obtain its IP by filtering and blocking the DHCP packets. I used 'scapy' to sniff and create a 'PCAP' log of the DHCP packets but I cannot block the packets.

Is there any way in which I can block the packets from reaching the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this is what a "firewall" can do. It has to happen on kernel level rather than on the application level. If you are on Linux, then make use of the netfilter kernel modules via [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables). You will have to perform some research on this topic before you'll feel comfortable with it.

Comment: Unfortunatley I am working on Windows. As of now I have seperated the two interfaces. Now I will be working on the bridging so that selective packets can be transferred.

Comment: I am continuing this work like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619068/network-bridge-using-scapy-and-python)